Set client_max_body_size for specific path in ingress-nginx
I'm trying to setup a custom client_max_body_size of 16M for a specific location pattern using ingress-nginx. I used the following annotation:
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      location /api/upload-endpoint {
        client_max_body_size 16M;
      }

Which renders into a location block like this on the NGINX pod:
                location / {

                        set $namespace      "my-namespace-name";
                        set $ingress_name   "my-ingress-name";
                        set $service_name   "my-service-name";
                        set $service_port   "http";
                        set $location_path  "/";
                        set $global_rate_limit_exceeding n;

                        // REMOVED A BUNCH OF OTHER CONFIGS HERE

                        client_max_body_size                    1m;

                        location /api/upload-endpoint {
                                client_max_body_size 16m;
                        }

                        grpc_pass grpc://upstream_balancer;

                        proxy_redirect                          off;

                }


The problem:
NGINX returns 503 errors, presumably because the nested location block does not have an upstream defined. I expected that it would take the parent's upstream, but it doesn't seem to be happening. If I change my configuration-snippet body to return 403; NGINX will return a 403 error, so the matching pattern works fine at least!

Hi kentor have you gone through this solution posted on ServerFault..? As per the discussion in this answer you either need to have a separate ingress resource for that particular sub-domain for limiting the client_max_body_size or need to use configuration-snippet block.

Yes I've seen that, the configuration-snippet solution is what I'd be looking for, but it doesn't work. Someone mentioned in the comment that they are also getting 503 errors, just like me. A separate ingress resource is something I'd like to avoid, but is currently my fallback solution.

if configuration-snippet is not working for you, we can try configuring server block using server-snippet annotation.

I tried some server snippet but it said I wouldn't be allowed to change the client directive there.
